# NSURLConnection and NSURLConnectionDelegate work on different thread

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

as descripted in the title, I did some NSURLConnection like this. But I found that the delegate method couldn't get run. Anyone knows how to deal with it ?

edit:
my delegate works on the main thread, while NSURLConnection works on an operation queue. Now the case is :NSURLConnection works fine, but delegate won't run.

edit 2:
I used the class method [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:]

here is on my main queue

```
 NSOperationQueue *queuePhoto = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
 NSInvocationOperation *invocationOperationPhotos = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self   selector:@selector(transferToServerAddimages:) object:arrayOfASection]; 
//                        [invocationOperationPhotos addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isExecuting" options:0 context:invocationOperationPhotos];
 //                        [invocationOperationPhotos addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isCancelled" options:0 context:invocationOperationPhotos];
//                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(<#selector#>) name:@"isExecuting" object:nil];
                        [invocationOperationPhotos setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh];
                    [queuePhoto addOperation:invocationOperationPhotos];
                    [mutableArrayPhotoQueue addObject:queuePhoto];
                    [invocationOperationPhotos release];
                    [queuePhoto release];
```

here is my NSURLConnnection:

```
- (void) transferToServerAddimages:(NSArray *) arrayToAdd
{
NSLog(@"[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]: %@", [NSOperationQueue currentQueue]);

NSString *murphoAppPrefix = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] murphoAppPrefix];
// setting up the request object now
NSString *urlString = [murphoAppPrefix stringByAppendingString:@"addPhotos.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
 add some header info now
 we always need a boundary when we post a file
 also we need to set the content type
 */
// set header value ,   some random text that will never occur in the body
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//  email part    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n%@", self.trip.whoCreate.email] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  password part
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n%@", self.trip.whoCreate.psw] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  image part
NSInteger subCount=0;
for (NSDictionary *aDict in arrayToAdd) {
    //  belonging part

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"r_whichShortTrip%d\"\r\n\r\n%@", subCount, [aDict objectForKey:@"r_whichShortTrip"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uniqueId%d\"\r\n\r\n%@", subCount, [aDict objectForKey:@"uniqueId"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"createdTime%d\"\r\n\r\n%@", subCount, [aDict objectForKey:@"createdTime"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    UIImage *imageFile = [aDict objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile, 1.0);
    NSString *imageName = [[URLConnect createUUID] stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: 
                       @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image%d\"; filename=%@\r\n", subCount, imageName]                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    UIImage *thumbnail = [aDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    NSData *thumbnailData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 1)];
    NSString *thumbnailName = [[URLConnect createUUID] stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: 
                       @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"thumbnail%d\"; filename=%@\r\n", subCount++, thumbnailName]                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:thumbnailData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

}

here is my delegate:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] mArrayOfFailedConnection] addObject:connection];
     [connection cancel];
     connection = nil;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connection: %@", connection);
}
```

Comment: If your thread has no run loop the NSURLConnection won't work.

Comment: have u added this line  [connection startConnection];

Comment: @Kevin Ballard, as edited just now, delegate is on the main thread and won't work, not the NSURLConnection.

Comment: @Arundhati, I used the class method `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:]`.

Comment: @Anna you must _start_ the connection on a thread with a run loop. The delegate methods will then be called on that thread. The connection IO itself always happens on another thread managed by Foundation.

Comment: @Jason Coco : I don't think _start_ is needed. Shown below(from [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html]  
    - (void)start
    Discussion
    Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection     with the initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO for the startImmediately parameter. If you don’t schedule the connection in a run loop or an operation queue before calling this method, the connection is scheduled in the current run loop in the default mode.**

Comment: Start is not needed but it's called implicitly by those other methods. Your connection is being started on a thread that has no runloop installed (whatever thread the operation gets dispatched to) and therefore you will never get delegate callbacks. Dispatch your operation to the main queue: [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:myAsyncNetworkOperation]

Comment: @Mehul, I have pasted my code. Please check

Comment: @JasonCoco, I have pasted my code, plz check. btw, I'm trying to add a  _start_.

Comment: @JasonCoco, I tried the code:    [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] start]; but delegate still won't run.

Comment: @anna your queuePhoto operation queue dispatches to a background thread with no runloop installed. That is your problem. Add the operation to the mainQueue as returned by NSOperationQueue.

Comment: @JasonCoco, mainQueue:Returns the operation queue associated with the main thread. If I dispatch my operation to the mainQueue, I'm afraid it would block the app or at least decrease the speed. So, is there any other way?

Comment: Well, you said you wanted the delegate callbacks on the main thread anyway, so that's how you get it. The actual networking IO is done on a private thread and does not block the main thread. Just make sure to return from delegate methods as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you set selector for operation as "transferToServerAddimages" that means when this function would executed completely your operation would be finished, also since NSUrlConnection calls its delegates on that same thread, on which it was started, so its probable that thread (OperationQueue) was finished before response arrived. If you indeed want to use NSOperationQueue then a better function to use is "sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:" of NSUrlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

What's the delegate, the `NSOperation`? One possibility is your operation is calling `-[connectionWithRequest:delegate:]` and exit, which causes it to finish and be deleted. Put an `NSLog` in the operation's dealloc to see if its running.

Assuming all the operation does is `NSURLConnection` transations, you don't need to wrap the transaction in an `NSOperation` to get concurrency, since those transations are asynchronous already. But if you really want to use `NSOperation` (for coordination purposes etc), make it a "concurrent" one and put it on the main queue. Those kind are trickier but there are examples around.